# Data skipped while writing Spark Streaming output to HDFS

Tags: java, apache-spark, hdfs, spark-streaming

I'm running a Spark Streaming application for every 10 seconds, its job is to consume data from kafka, transform it and store it into HDFS based on the key. i.e, a file per unique key. I'm using the Hadoop's saveAsHadoopFile() API to store the output, I see that a file gets generated for every unique key, but the issue is that only one row gets stored for each of the unique key though the DStream has more rows for the same key.

For example, consider the following DStream which has one unique key,

```
  key                  value
 =====   =====================================
 Key_1   183.33 70.0 0.12 1.0 1.0 1.0 11.0 4.0 
 Key_1   184.33 70.0 1.12 1.0 1.0 1.0 11.0 4.0 
 Key_1   181.33 70.0 2.12 1.0 1.0 1.0 11.0 4.0 
 Key_1   185.33 70.0 1.12 1.0 1.0 1.0 11.0 4.0 
 Key_1   185.33 70.0 0.12 1.0 1.0 1.0 11.0 4.0
```

I see only one row (instead of 5 rows) gets stored in the HDFS file,

```
185.33 70.0 0.12 1.0 1.0 1.0 11.0 4.0
```

The following code is used to store the output into HDFS,

```
dStream.foreachRDD(new Function<JavaPairRDD<String, String>, Void> () {
    @Override
    public Void call(JavaPairRDD<String, String> pairRDD) throws Exception {
        long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int randomInt = random.nextInt();
        pairRDD.saveAsHadoopFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/application-" + timestamp +"-"+ randomInt, String.class, String.class, RDDMultipleTextOutputFormat.class);
    }
});
```

where the implementation of RDDMultipleTextOutputFormat is as follows,

```
public class RDDMultipleTextOutputFormat<K,V> extends    MultipleTextOutputFormat<K,V> {

    public K generateActualKey(K key, V value) { 
        return null;
    }

    public String generateFileNameForKeyValue(K key, V value, String name) { 
        return key.toString();
    }
}
```

Please let me know if I'm missing anything? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Because the key is same, the value is getting replaced every time and hence you are getting the last value supplied to hadoop.

Comment: How can i make it not to overwrite? ... Actually i'm storing the pairRDD, that must store the entire RDD and should not overwrite.

Comment: Instead of using the same key, you can use rdd.zipWithUniqueId() to obtain different keys and then dump it to our hdfs.
Just try it.

Comment: my requirement is to store all the lines of a key with a single file. Will rdd.zipWithUniqueId() do the same?

Comment: rdd.zipWithUniqueId() is used to generate unique keys but do you already have your keys ?

Comment: Yes, i have my keys already and there will be multiple unique keys, and each key might have 5 to 10 rows in each batch interval. So i need to store them in the corresponding key file.

Comment: can you please try this, I'm not sure if it could work on hdfs but lets give it a try.
    val keys = pairRdd.map(_._1).distinct().toArray().toSeq

    keys.foreach { key => pairRdd.filter(_._1.equals(key)).map(_._2).saveAsHadoopFile(key) }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92020/discussion-between-kshitij-kulshrestha-and-sathish).

Comment: please  upvote if you have found it some what helpful.